# Angular 5.0.4 - routerLinkActive not working with queryParamsHandling

Tags: angular

I am using a button group and the `[routerLinkActive]="['active']"` does not work when I add `queryParamsHandling="preserve"`. I am using Angular 5.0.4.

Here is the code:

```
<div class="btn-group" role="group">
    <button [routerLink]="['route1']" [routerLinkActive]="['active']" queryParamsHandling="preserve" class="btn btn-secondary btn-responsive">route1</button>
    <button [routerLink]="['route2']" [routerLinkActive]="['active']" queryParamsHandling="preserve" class="btn btn-secondary btn-responsive">route2</button>
    <button [routerLink]="['route3']" [routerLinkActive]="['active']" queryParamsHandling="preserve" class="btn btn-secondary btn-responsive">route3</button>
</div>
```

Why when I add `queryParamsHandling="preserve"` does the button not become active when the route is selected?

Comment: can u share your routing module ?

Answer (score 0):

Most probably Bootstrap is overriding your class.
To be sure you should provide a Stackblitz.

You could try adding `!important` or load you custom styles after bootstrap styles.